# Designer tag without SharePoint

Tags: support, tagging

I can see we have a tag called "designer". I am pretty sure this was called SharePoint-designer before. Designer doesnt make sense, it is a product called "SharePoint Designer". I hope we soon can get to a point where the SharePoint experts can regain control on tags on this site, because this SharePoint-tag-deletion ting has really become rather silly...

I apologize in advance if the tag has been designer all along, but i am pretty sure it has changed.

Comment: please could you change it back to sharepoint-designer?

Answer (score 2):

I think this whole "SE deciding about the content" in general is off the rails. The 2007 and 2010 tags don't make sense to me (we were fine with the sharepoint- lead before), sharepoint-designer became designer (different meaning), etc.

"I leave that to your mods" after the SE folks mess with stuff is just rude. I truly wonder whether this move to SE 2.0 may end up detracting enough from the SharePoint Overflow mission as to significantly diminish the site's usefulness. I have sent people here first for many types of questions, but my loyalty is waning.

Comment: So, if the OP saying "I hope we soon can get to a point where the SharePoint experts can regain control on tags on this site" and then me doing *exactly that* by saying "I'll leave that to the mods" is me being rude, what did you want me to do in this situation?

Comment: Who changed the sharepoint-designer tag in the first place? Who pushed changing from sharepoint-2007 and -2010 to just 2007 and 2010? I don't *believe* it was "our" mods. Point is, there seem to be SE decisions about the SharePoint content corpus driven not from knowledge of the SharePoint domain but by some other mythical reasons.

Comment: I'll just point you to the [other](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/19/2834) [three](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/142/2834) [questions](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/153/2834).  There are no mythical reasons going on here.  There is experience with the SE engine and knowing what works and what is actively harmful to a site.

Comment: It's clear we are having some teething issues as part of the migration, I suspect mostly due to changes in culture and how the site now needs to be run. We also have two mods still learning the system and myself who has been flat out at work over the last few days while the migration happened. Please be patient, it's early days and we will resolve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the [SPO data dump](http://sstatic.net/area51/datadumps/042011%20SharePoint%20Overflow.zip) for [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/916/3114); it's tagged as [sharepoint-designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-designer) in the dump but [designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/designer) here, so you're right that it changed. Can you just change it back? I assume the devs didn't realize the product was actually called "SharePoint Designer", so you might want to let a community coordinator know if you haven't already

Comment: I have no idea, i just dont like this tampering with tags without being asked. We really need to be more involved in this process, I appreciate the old content being migrated, i **really** do, but i am a bit uneasy with what gets changed and for what reasons. For somebody who dont know anything about SharePoint it may seem a good idea to take the SharePoint part out of that tag, but since its the name of the tool, and not about solution design or similar it makes absolutely no sense to rename that tag to "designer". And thats just the tag i noticed, one of what? 100?

Answer (score -2):

The old questions from SharePoint Overflow had all the version tags in them that have been discussed in the last few days.  I looked at what tags were renamed as part of that process, and made sure to handle those that reappeared as part of the import.

Comment: I dont think this is about versions. Se my comment to Michael Mrozek

Comment: I just looked at what tags had been merged at the same time.  *shrugs*

Comment: @Rebecca Please could you change it back? This particular one doesn't actually make sense if you remove "sharepoint-".

Comment: @SPDoctor, I leave that to your mods.

Comment: @Anders Please could you change it back?

Comment: Im not sure how... I can set that I can merge tags but not rename. Im still pretty green as mod so we will have to ask @alexangas or @kitmenke

Comment: @AndersRask It's under "Mod", "Links" and has been done.